# What is the difference between projection and displayprojection for a Map in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am familiarizing myself with Openlayers, and am having trouble with understanding the *projection* and *displayprojection* properties for a Map.

When the map is initialized with the following code:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {           
        numZoomLevels: 20,
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),
        displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG: 4326")
        });
```

What exactly is happening?

The documentation of the [OpenLayers.Map](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html) says that

**projection** -Set in the map options to override the default projection string [in] this map - also set maxExtent, maxResolution, and units if appropriate.  Default is “EPSG:4326”.

while **displayProjection** is the Projection used by several controls to display data to user.  If this property is set, it will be set on any control which has a null displayProjection property at the time the control is added to the map.

This does not make it clear.

Could someone explain what exactly do these two option do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the OpenLayers Beginner's guide:

> **This is a property that is used mainly by controls which show
>   coordinate information.** By  setting this property on the map object,
>   any control that has a  displayProjection  property will be set to
>   this value. Controls, such as the MousePosition  control, can display 
>   coordinates in the displayProjection. So, your map could be in a
>   different projection  than what you wish to **display the coordinates**
>   in. However, to use a displayProjection  other than EPSG:4326 or
>   EPSG:900913, Proj4js must be included on your page. **This property
>   comes in very handy if, for instance, your map is in a spherical
>   Mercator  projection (i.e., EPSG:900913), but you might wish to
>   display coordinates in another  projection, like EPSG:4326 (to display
>   lon/lat coordinates).**

The bold parts should give you an idea. I hope it helps.

Comment: So to clarify, Projection is the coordinate system of the **map**, while  displayProjection is the coordinate system used **only** by controls like Permalink & MousePosition etc.

Comment: Yes. More or less. Controls that show coordinate information.